# How to send a two argument function in props in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a function which takes two arguments earlier it used to take only one argument so to pass it in props as this:-

```
mixed1.map((cat1) => (<ServicesCategoryOption category1={cat1.categories} setacatid={i=>this.setacatid(i)}/>))
```

But now I changed setacatid as:-

```
setacatid(a,b){
    console.log(b);
    this.setState({                     
        catidofclicked:a,
        catnameofclicked:b
    },function(){
        localStorage.setItem('selecteditem',this.state.catidofclicked);
        localStorage.setItem('selectedname',this.state.catnameofclicked);           
    });
}
```

So it takes two arguments a and b how to pass it in props now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass multiple arguments to the event handlers when you are using the arrow function syntax like

```
mixed1.map((cat1) => (
      <ServicesCategoryOption 
           category1={cat1.categories} 
           setacatid={(a, b)=>this.setacatid(a, b)}
      />
))
```

or you can simply write

```
mixed1.map((cat1) => (
      <ServicesCategoryOption 
           category1={cat1.categories} 
           setacatid={(...args)=>this.setacatid(...args)}
      />
))
```

which can simply be written as

```
mixed1.map((cat1) => (
      <ServicesCategoryOption 
           category1={cat1.categories} 
           setacatid={this.setacatid}
      />
))
```

The only advantage of using the first method is that you can pass custom values too like

```
mixed1.map((cat1) => (
      <ServicesCategoryOption 
           category1={cat1.categories} 
           setacatid={(...args)=>this.setacatid(1, ...args)}
      />
))
```

in which way you can pass a many parameters from child and receive them in the function without worrying about adding a parameter everytime you want to add a new one

Comment: The expression `setacatid={(...args)=>this.setacatid(...args)}` is exactly same as  `setacatid={this.setacatid}` but second is shortly and less resource-intensive.

Comment: @oklas, true, the only advantage of using ...args can come in case when you wish to pass custom params along with those received by the function.

Answer (score 0):

You can do whatever you want:

```js
<ServicesCategoryOption
  category1={cat1.categories}
  setacatid={i=>this.setacatid(i,10)}
/>

<ServicesCategoryOption
  category1={cat1.categories}
  setacatid={(i, j)=>this.setacatid(i, j)}
/>

<ServicesCategoryOption
  category1={cat1.categories}
  setacatid={this.setacatid}
/>
```